# Multiple statements in initialization of FOR loop

Tags: c#

I need to declare `i` and reinitialize `j` at the start of a for loop at the same time. However,

```
int j;
for (int i = 0, j = 0; true;) { // Do sth }
```

Says: A local or parameter named 'j' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define local parameter.

```
int j;
for (j = 0, int i = 0; true;) { // Do sth }
```

Says: Invalid expression term 'int'

Is there a way to do it? Any knowledge is appreciated.

**Note 1**: I know to put `j = 0` right before for statemnt, that is not what I want.

**Note 2**: All of the following works.

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0, j = 0; true;) { // Do sth }
```

.

```
for (int i = 0, int j = 0; true;) { // Do sth }
```

.

```
int i;
for (Foo(), i = 0; true;) { // Do sth }
```

Comment: Doesn't Note 2 answer your question?

Comment: @john I don't see how **Note 2** answers my question. I want the scope of i to be the for loop and the scope of j is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem, that this line (if used outside of for-loop): `int i = 0, j = 0;` is exactly the same as `int i = 0; int j = 0`. But, you still able to do this:

```
int j;
for (int i = j = 0; true;) { // Do sth }
```

Comment: Reason why you can do it is that assignment opertor actually returns the value it assigns right? (This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you soo much.)

Comment: yep. Pretty useful:)

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is

```
//int j;
for (int i = 0, j = 0; true;) { // Do sth }
```

When you do something like this

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
```

What you are saying is create a new variable of `int i` and `int j`, obviously you are trying to declare the same variable twice in the same scope,

Or alternatively you can do

```
int i;
int j;
for (i = 0, j = 0; true;) { // Do sth }
```

**Update**

> In first one j is needed to be created and used before for loop. In
>   the alternate version the scope of i is not only for loop. I
>   appreciate the possible workarounds but this is not what i asked

There is no work around, this is a scope problem, if you are using the variables in other scopes, you need to scope the variables appropriately or change their names accordingly. Simple fix, don't use i, in the same scope if you declare it before the for. i.e Change the name of i, further down

Comment: In first one j is needed to be created and used before for loop. In the alternate version the scope of i is not only for loop. I appreciate the possible workarounds but this is not what i asked.

Answer (score 1):

I think this solves the scoping problem.

```
int j;
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0, j = 0; true;)
    {
        // Do sth
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that should do it.